# Azure Service Bus: Maintain the order of messages while retrieving from multiple topics

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using `Topics` in `Azure Service Bus` as I want to get message in multiple applications for the single event.

So imagine my topics in azure service bus are like these:

```
name      |    subscription count      |   enable partitioning
          |                            |
topic-1   |           2                |       false
topic-2   |           2                |       false
topic-3   |           2                |       false
topic-4   |           2                |       false
topic-5   |           2                |       false
```

Now I want to maintain the order while I get messages from different topic.

I know that If I set *`SessionId`* while pushing messages to topics, I will get the messages in the same order. But this is true for pushing/ retrieving messages within single `topic`.

**My question is- How would I maintain the order of messages while receiving the messages from different topics?** Which means that- If I push messages in the the order like- push messages to `topic-5, topic-1, topic-3 and topic-2`, then I should get the messages in the same order how they pushed in different topics, respectively from  `topic-5, topic-1, topic-3 and topic-2`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically, you can not. You would have to implement manual checks and reorder messages afterwards in your code.

Comment: I'd be very curous to learn about usecase that demands this.